# Spring security remember-me with customAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me

I'm using `CustomAuthentication` provider to authenticate which extends `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`. This I had to do because I wanted to authenticate against a webservice and needed both userid as well as password. This was the only class which allowed me to do so.
Now I'm facing issues implementing remember-me functionality for this, here is my security-context file -

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>       
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/dashboard1.html#meetings"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />
</http>

<beans:bean name="customAuthenticationProvider" class = "com.component.WebServiceUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider"/>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref = "customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Now I'm trying to implement remember me, but it's enforcing me to have user detail service that I can't have as I need both username and password to authenticate agains my web service and method exposed by userdetailservice gives only username not password and that's the reason I had to use customAuthentication at first place.

Comment: You haven't actually said what your issues are so you should probably edit your question to clarify. Also, you don't need to extend `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`. You can just implement the `AuthenticationProvider` interface directly.

Comment: Hi Luke, I've completed my question now. And AbstractUserDeta..... I used because I wanted to provide implementation only for method authenticate and that's what abstractUs.. is for.

Answer (score 0):

Remember-me is an alternative way of authenticating a user, so when it receives a remember-me cookie it needs to validate it and load information for the user to provide it to the application. To do that it uses the `UserDetailsService` interface.

The basic implementation `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` needs access to the password in order to verify the token. If your system can't provide that, then you can't use it.

The alternative is `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`, which uses a database to store the remember-me tokens. It doesn't need access to the password, but you will still need to implement a `UserDetailsService` to allow it to load information for the authenticated user. The `UserDetails` object it returns doesn't need to contain a password, but it should contain the username as a minimum so that you can tell who is logged in.